# How do I print % percent symbol in Drupal's t() function?

Tags: drupal, translation

How do I print % percent symbol in Drupal's t() function?

```
<?=t('% Daily Value') ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried '\% Daily Value'? (wondering if you can escape the %)

Comment: Of course, I did. With no luck :(

Comment: The code you've written returns the string '% Daily Value' in Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 (I've just tried it)

Comment: You're right Clive. It was error on my side.

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal `t()` function uses `%`, `@` and `!` as variable reference operators, the difference being the kind of substitution that is done on the variable at the time of substitution in the string.

The thing is, in order for this to work, you have to have specified an exact match of the variable as an array key in the second argument to `t()`. In the case of your example you are not providing an array of replacement values, so no substitutions will be attempted.

Your `%` sign should come through without any further need for escaping.